# Is there a way to dynamically build Ant elements from within an Ant script?

Tags: ant

The question probably isn't very clear so let me illustrate what I mean with an example. Say that I want to copy a few folders:

```
<copy todir="..." overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="dir1" />
    <fileset dir="dir2" />
    <fileset dir="dir3" />
    ...
</copy>
```

But instead of hardcoding those folders in a script, I need to load them from a text file that looks like this:

```
Directories to copy:
  dir1
  dir2
  dir3
  ...
```

So I somehow **need to load the text file, parse it, find out which directories should be copied and the construct elements from it** (`<copy>` and `<fileset>` are just examples).

Is it possible to achieve that from *within Ant* without executing some transformation (e.g., XSLT) on my build.xml file?

Comment: Whoa there, partner.  I would definitely exclude manipulation of the build file.  Aside from being extremely unpredictable, it's also unmaintainable.  There's a better way I'm sure.  Now what is the criteria for copying files on these folders?

Comment: are you able to modify the format of your text file?

Comment: @Neil Copy is just an example (actually my task is to dynamically construct `<include-file>`s for Flex's `<compc>` task.

@orzechowskid No I am not.

Answer (score 2):

since you're not able to modify the format of the input text file, the best way I can think of doing what you want is to:

1.create a [shell|Perl|etc] script which generates XML from your original file.  This can either be a snippet of XML or a complete Ant file.

2.run that script before invoking Ant.

3.import the generated XML into your Ant file (see the relevant Ant documentation at http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#xml-entity-include).

Comment: Thanks for the link to including XML entities, I forgot I could use that technique and was only looking at the Include task. However, I'd to build my stuff in one step only if at all possible. I may be lucky though - the task that I need to execute (Flex's `compc`) can actually read an external config file so hopefully I just need to execute a file transformation task before I come to `compc`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to accomplish what you want to do with ant is to use the [ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) foreach task to read the file and act on each line.  The ant targets would look something like this:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
<path id="dirlists">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/dirlists">
        <include name="**/*.txt" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="runCopy">
    <foreach target="_copyDir" param="dirPath">
        <path refid="dirlists"/>
    </foreach>
</target>   

<target name="_copyDir">
    <copy todir="..." overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${dirPath}"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

This will read any .txt files in a folder named dirlists, and for every line in each file do a copy from the dir specified by that line to the target dir ...

Comment: Thanks but as I have noted in the question `copy` and `fileset` were just examples and what I'm after is dynamically generating nested elements. Executing the same task multiple times would not work in my case.

Comment: Ah,I see.  I have wanted to do that same thing before, but never found a way to do nested elements dynamically with ant.